# Ruby on Rails: Using bootstrap without require_tree breaks my stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to migrate to Bootstrap 4 in my Ruby on Rails project, following the [github installation guide](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem)

It recommends that in my `application.scss` file, I remove `*= require_tree`

However, when I do this, none of my custom CSS files appear. If `require_tree` DOES tell the asset pipeline to include all of the specified files in the directory, how else would the asset pipeline know to do this?

I've been trying to find an answer to this problem and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you would try to work with `css` and `scss` at a time, Right? You can do this the several ways like if you need to use only one file like `application.scss` then you can rename the file again e.g `application.css.scss` then for `scss` you would follow this

```
@import "bootstrap";
...
```

then for custom `css` above in the `@import` variable

```
 /*
 *= require custom
 *= require custom_another
 */
```

make sure this custom file is formatted with `.css` and it's inside `assets/stylesheets` folder.

For `saas` file will use `@import` & for `css` file will use `*= require`.

Now if you need to use separate files for `css` & `scss` then it would look like this `application.css`

```
 /*
 *= require custom
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

you can leave that `application.css` and for `scss` you can create a custom file inside `assets/stylesheets` like `custom.scss` then

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: I figured the solution would look like this, and it kind of works, except I lose access to a lot of bootstrap variables. Like `$primary` and `$gray` (2 diff basic colors)